# How to read text from file from one value to other in c#

Tags: c#

I`m new in c#, I'm still learning that language. Now I try to make app which read text and to my data i need only specific lines. Text look like:

```
[HAEDING]
Some value

[HEADING]
Some other value

[HEADING]
Some other text
and continuation of this text in new line

[HEADING]
Last text
```

I try to write method which read text and put it into string[] by split it like this:

```
string[0] = Some value
string[1] = Some other value
string[2] = Some other text and continuation of this text in new line
string[3] = Last text
```

So I want to read line from value [HEADING] to value new line which is empty. I thought that is should write by ReadAllLines and line by line check start position on value [HEADING] and end position on empty value in new line. I try this code:

```
string s = "mystring";
int start = s.IndexOf("[HEADING]");
int end = s.IndexOf("\n", start);
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

but it's substring to all lines in my text not like loop between first [HEADING] and empty new line, second etc.
Maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: is this the content of a *.ini file? Please post the code that actually read the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which avoids the substring/index checking, which could potentially be fraught with errors.

There are answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116471/64348) that use LINQ, but for a newcomer to the language, basic looping is an OK place to start. Also, this is not necessarily the best solution for efficiency or whatever.

This `foreach` loop will handle your case, and *some* of the "dirty" cases.

```
var segments = new List<string>();
bool headingChanged = false;
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("somefilename.txt"))
{
    // skip blank lines
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)) continue;

    // detect a heading
    if (line.Contains("[HEADING]")
    {
        headingChanged = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (headingChanged)
    {
        segments.Add(line);

        // this keeps us working on the same segment if there
        // are more lines to be added to the segment
        headingChanged = false;
    }
    else
    {
        segments[segments.Length - 1] += " ";
        segments[segments.Length - 1] += line;
        // you could replace the above two lines with string interpolation...
        // segments[segments.Length - 1] = $"{segments[segments.Length - 1]} {line}";
    }
}
```

In the above loop, the `ReadAllLines` obviates the need to check for `\r` and `\n`. `Contains` will handle `[HEADING]` no matter where it changes.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to split the string by `"[HEADING]"` to get the strings between these lines. Then you could join each string into a single line and trim the whitespace around the strings:

```
string content = @"[HEADING]
Some value

[HEADING]
Some other value

[HEADING]
Some other text
and continuation of this text in new line

[HEADING]
Last text";

var segments = content.Split(new[] { "[HEADING]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  // Split into multiple strings
    .Select(p=>p.Replace("\r\n"," ").Replace("\r"," ").Replace("\n"," ").Trim()) // Join each single string into single line
    .ToArray();
```

Result:

```
segments[0] = "Some value"
segments[1] = "Some other value"
segments[2] = "Some other text and continuation of this text in new line"
segments[3] = "Last text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need substring, you can just compare the value s == "[HEADING]".

Here's an easy to understand example:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFilePath);

var resultLines = new List<String>();

var collectedText = new List<String>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line == "[HEADING]")
    {
        collectedText = new List<String>();
    }
    else if (line != "")
    {
        collectedText.Add(line);
    }
    else //if (line == "")
    {
        var joinedText = String.Join(" ", collectedText);
        resultLines.Add(joinedText);
    }
}

return resultLines.ToArray();
```

the loop does this:

1. we go line by line
2. "start collecting" (create list) when we encounter with "[HEADING]" line
3. "collect" (add to list) line if not empty
4. "finish collecting" (concat and add to results list) when line is empty